# Orbit of the Earth

Tags: solar-system, celestial-mechanics, tidal-effect

The question I have really is in a few parts.

1. First what if anything could cause the orbit of the Earth to start to diminish start to go towards the Sun closer on each revolution? 
   ( edit to remove all but one question my apologies for that)

Comment: This is too many questions in one. Its always recommended that you ask different questions separately!

Comment: Okay sorry for so many questions in one post. The main thing that I would like an answer to is what could cause this to happen?

Answer (score 1):

The Earth, actually, is moving away from the sun at a very slow rate. The tidal forces between the Earth-Sun pair slowly transfers the Sun's rotational energy to the Earth, and this causes the Earth to move further and further away. (albeit this happens almost unnoticeably slowly.)

The Earth moon system is the most well known case when it comes to tidal interactions like this one. The first few lines on this page explain it clearly: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_acceleration

Comment: Quantify please. Is this bigger or smaller than the effects of solar mass loss?

Answer (score 0):

As Hritik said, it's generally better to ask one quesiton at a time, and it's also a good idea to do a little reseach yourself.  Most of these questions are researchable, but they're also pretty straight forward, so I'll give it a shot.

> First what if anything could cause the orbit of the Earth to start to
>   diminish start to go towards the Sun closer on each revolution?

A few things, none of the likely.   One, if Venus were larger, the Venus gravitational tug on the Earth could cause Earth to slowly spiral inwards, at least until it passes Venus at which point, the two planets could interact with each other more strongly and any number of things could happen.

or, if the solar system was to pass through a gas cloud, a rather dense one where the gas cloud would provide some (admittedly quite small) but some friction to slow the earth's orbit and at the same time the sun added mass.   For a degrading orbit, you'd want a very big gas cloud, that would take us a long time to pass through.  Once outside of the cloud, the degrading would stop.   You can't spiral a planet into a star like water spirals down a drain, because that doesn't follow conservation of energy.

or, if the sun was to stop spinning, and if that happened, the tidal effects that push the earth out, ever so slowly would reverse and drag the earth in, ever so slowly.

or, if the sun was to get close to a 2nd star and they would go binary, in effect, if the entire solar system was to star orbiting a larger star or neutron star or black hole, then the larger star would have tidal effects that would draw the earth slowly into the sun.

None of these things are likely to happen but all 4 are theoretical answers to your question.

If a rogue planet was to fly past earth, it could change our orbit, perhaps throw us into the sun, but changing an orbit is different than degrading.   degrading orbits require specific circumstances and in the scenario you suggest, they are unlikely to happen.

It happened to Kirk a lot, but that wasn't very accurate.  :-)

Now, some orbits degrade.   Lunar orbits degrade cause the Earth steals energy from any object that orbits the moon via tidal force, and satellite orbits can degrade, but that's cause they pass through thin parts of the Earth's atmosphere, creating drag.

The Earth's orbit around the sun doesn't degrade, not measurably anyway, not till long after the sun goes red giant.

> Second how long could the Earth as we know it survive in some way and
>   sustain our life?

Well, this is unanswerable cause we haven't explained precisely what the situation is or how fast it's degrading.   Without paramaters, there's no answer to this.

> Third is there any way that we as humans could reverse this decline?

Not easily, depending on how fast it was, but it's not impossible.  It's a question of harnessing enough energy.   A more realistic problem we may face (eventually) is the sun is gradually growing brighter and the amount of energy that shines on earth is slowly increasing, about 1% more light and energy every 100 million years or so.   We're going to want to star thinking about pushing the earth away form the sun is perhaps 50 million years or so . . . . give or take.

or maybe not, by building a lot of reflective solar panels, we may be able to collect energy from the sun and keep the earth at a desirable temperature, we might be fine for a couple hundred million years or so.

> What would be a long amount time, best case scenario, I mean years of
>   decline before we as Humans could no longer survive on this planet
>   i.e. to hot, too much radiation, and or anything that would be caused
>   by slowly getting closer to the Sun?

Without saying how fast the decline is, talking about "How long" is meaningless.   It's like asking "how long will it take a car to crash into a lamppost that's 20 feet away?   without knowing the speed of the car, the question is meaningless.

A better question would be, how close to the sun could the earth be, where we could still survive, and even that is pretty hard to answer cause there's too many moving parts to the atmosphere, but there is a point where higher temperatures would do a few things, such as evaporate significantly more water, which in and of itself would trap more heat, and as trees die and oceans warm, CO2 would be released from both land (dying trees) and warming oceans.   Perhaps, trapped methane in the oceans as well, so there is a very real doomsday-ish scenario if the earth was just 5 or 10% closer to the sun, but, that's not likely to happen cause, as Hritik pointed out, we're moving away from the sun, very gradually.

Now, with better technology and building giant mirrors, we could probably survive being 10% closer to the sun, but if it was to happen today it would be a pretty huge problem for us.

But none of these things (except the sun gradually growing brighter) are likely to happen.   The energy in an orbit tends to stay pretty consistent and it's pretty enormous.   You'd practically have to hit the Earth with something the size of the Moon to measurably change it's orbit and if that happened, our orbit would be the least of our worries.

Update:   Gas clouds do exist, but they're mostly too thin to do what I suggested.  There's 2 things going on in they gas cloud scenario.   One is resistance, but when you're talking about something the size and mass of the Earth and something as light and diffuse as a cloud of gas in space, the slow down is so little as to be effectively negligible.

As far as the sun gaining mass, lets say you flip a switch and the sun is 10% heavier would the Earth spiral in - no.   What would happen would be similar to giving the earth a significant tug towards the sun, but as the earth falls towards the sun it gains velocity and in gaining velocity, it enters into a new lower, faster moving orbit.   We think everything falls towards the ground cause that's what we see on earth, but in space it's different.    Things mostly fall around other things in space.   Orbits are essentially free fall.   Spiraling into isn't a good way to think about orbits, not that it can't happen cause it happens with satellites around the earth (due to air resistance).  Hubble was designed to decay and fall back to Earth some 30-40 years after it was launched and lunar satellites decay into the moon because of the strong tidal effects from Earth, but with most solar-system orbits, decay doesn't happen very fast or often.    Phobos is spiraling into Mars but very slowly.   It'll be a few million orbits before it actually crashes into Mars.  That's a typical solar system orbital decay - very very slow.

Orbits are generally quite stable.

Comment: Thank you very much for making an attempt at my poorly asked questions.

Comment: I would like to look at some of your answer a bit deeper if you would entertain the idea for a bit longer. As to going through a gas cloud would that be deadly to humans just by passing through it. Or would we pass through it safely only to find our sun has gained mass and then we are slowly being pulled towards the sun. Another part would be a passing body of some sort that has enough mass of its own to push us again towards the sun. The rest of any questions I will gladly try at another time one at a time.

Answer (score -1):

Earth is in equilibrium in the space ( both rotational and translational) . The net ext force on earth is zero and hence torques too. Hence under any circumstance earth cannot deviate from its original path. It will continue to be moving as it was moving. 
There are many other theories which can lead to the decline of earth ( like black hole one) but nothing of your sort.

Comment: This is incorrect because the Earth actually is moving 'away' from the Sun because of Tidal interactions. (Also, to be in Equilibrium, the net force on a body needs to be zero.)

Comment: The net force on earth is actually zero otherwise the earth would be having different velocities- linear , angular and hence we would not be having 24 hours in each day , the hours would ne some day less some day more because now the earth wouldnt be under uniform rotation , similarly wouldnt be having 365 days in a year. These interactions like the tidal one you have mentioned bring abput a change in natural phenomena but do not change the motion of the earth or bring eart near sun.

Comment: If the net force on the Earth is zero, why is it revolving around the sun? Also, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tidal_acceleration

Comment: Being in equilibrium doesnt mean the body has to be at rest or no force acts on it. Forces act but the net ext force is zero which causes the earth to move with constant speed ( ofcourse there's a gravitational force on earth by the sun)

Comment: If there is no force the earth would move with constant velocity, which implies rectilinear, not curvilinear, motion. This is clearly incorrect.